# Kendo grid with Backbone model as datasource?

Tags: backbone.js, datasource, kendo-ui

Has anyone got an example they can share of a Kendo grid (or any Kendo object for that matter) that uses a Backbone model as its datasource?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it does provide a simple example of using the Kendo Grid with a Backbone Model.

https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-backbone

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that page no longer exists, but maybe I can find an archive of it somewhere. Thanks for taking the time to reply.